# Search a xml element by an attribute in php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, domdocument

I think the question is repeated but I'm not satisfied with the previous answers.

I have a XML file as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <forms xml:id="cust_type">
     <form>
        <element id="cust_type" type="dropdown" name="cust_type" desc="Customer Type*"  value="" div_attr="select_long" 
 class="required select" validate="required"></element>
<element type="text" name="form_no" desc="Form No"  div_attr="txt_short" value="" class="number" validate="numeric"></element>
</form> 
</forms>
```

I want to get only the element with the id="cust_type" or with name="cust_type".
But I'm not getting it.

Please suggest me the code to so using SimpleXML or DOMDocument.

Comment: http://php.net/domxpath - Please show what you have tried

Comment: I tried the following

    $file = file_get_contents('URL_TO_FILE'); $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadXML($file);

    print_r($doc->getElementById('cust_type'));

but got the output as

    DOMElement Object ( )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `simplexml`and `xpath`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$elements = $xml->xpath("//element[@id='cust_type' or @name='cust_type']");
foreach ($elements as $element) echo $element['name'] . "<br />";
```

see working demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/EzmGWJ